# Get number of rows with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, hssf

I try to count number of rows in a xls file with `Apache POI`. File contains 300 rows, but I get just 24 as output of both of these commands.

```
int noOfColumns = sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
int noOfColumns = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
```

There aren't any empty rows between lines in file.

Comment: you are getting row #0 as a base and then wondering why you don't get the row number? try using ``sh.getFirstRowNum()`` and ``sh.getLastRowNum()`` to get first and last row indexes. And by the way, ``Sheet`` implements ``Iterable<Row>`` so you can write ``for(Row r : sh) {}``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives right number of rows on a sheet:

```
int rnum = sheet.getLastRowNum() - sheet.getFirstRowNum();
```